# How to return a error message in json result in C#?

Tags: c#, json, api, http-post, jsonresult

This is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/bulkUpload")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public JsonResult bulkUpload(IFormFile file)
    {
        List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
        try
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (extension == ".csv")
            {
              .
              .
              .
            }
        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
          return json(new { errormessage ="invalid file extension"});
        }
     return jsonresult(inputs)
    }
```

In swagger api if I give a different file(diff extensions) like .txt or .xls it is giving error code:500.
But I want to return a error message as invalid file extension. PLease help on this code.

Comment: Have you tried `if(extension== ".txt" || extension == ".xls")return Json(new { errormessage ="invalid file extension"});`

Comment: before your try catch, do if(!extension.Equals(".csv")) throw new Exception("Invalid File Extension") 

validate request and throw invalid file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend a bit on what version of ASP.NET you are using, but you should be able to do something like:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/bulkUpload")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult bulkUpload(IFormFile file)
    {
        List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
        try
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (extension == ".csv")
            {
                // do the thing!
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("invalid file extension");
            // or try this:
            // return BadRequest(new JsonResult("invalid file extension"));
        }

        return new JsonResult("ok");
    }

}

public class Input
{

}
```

Here is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.responsemessageresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on it and some [examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/ResponseMessageResult/-/php-responsemessageresult-class-examples.html).

Comment: I am getting error at request.createerrorresponse as "httprequest" does not contain a definition for createerrorresponse.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.1 version

Comment: And have you included the System.Net.Http namespace?

Comment: yes I have included system.net.http namespace.

Comment: Okay, I updated my code example.  Hopefully this should work a bit smoother for you.

Comment: I  am getting error under badrequest as " Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult' to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult'

Comment: You need to change the return type to IActionResult, which is a base type of JsonResult.

Comment: It is giving error like "Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'IActionResult'

Comment: No, do not return new IActionResult.  you return new JsonResult, but in your method definition it should be public IActionResult bulkUpload(IFormatFile file).  Pleas refer to my example.

Comment: After changing that to IActionResult also the same error code:500 is coming in the response body. I want this "invalid file extension " to be displayed, if I upload different file with  extension other than csv.